# Using task method to update a row in datagrid/listview for each task/row

Tags: c#, listview, datagridview, datagrid

I've asked this question a few times but never managed to get to the bottom of it. Hopefully someone could help me as I am new to programming and C#.

I've got a button which adds `Tasks` to a `Task<List>` and then populates a `Datagrid` (previously Listview) with some values such as the `Task ID` and `Task Status`. Each `Task` I add contains the **same** `method` which should update the relevant `Status` for that `Task index`.

Please see below.

My listview:

```
namespace Something
{
public class listView
{ 
    private static ObservableCollection<listItems> _myList = new      ObservableCollection<listItems>();
    public static ObservableCollection<listItems> myList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
    }

    private static string _status;

    public class listItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void   OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public int id { get; set; }

        public string status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                if (_status != value)
                {
                    _status = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My mainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = listView.myList;
    }

  private void create_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvl.status = "Task ready to start";

        var repeat = int.Parse(taskNumber.Text);
        addTasks(repeat);

        run_btn.IsEnabled = true;
        create_btn.IsEnabled = false;
        taskNumber.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void run_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var Task in myTasks)
        {
            Task.Start();
        }
    }

    public void addTasks(int repeatCount)
    { 
        List<Task> myTasks = pTask.tasks();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++)
        {
            lvl.id++;
            int x = lvl.id;
            myTasks.Add(new Task(() => p.myAction(x)));
            listView.myList.Add(new listView.listItems
            {
                id = lvl.id,
                status = lvl.status,
            });
        }
    }
```

and then here's my `method` which calls `updateStatus` to find the rows `STATUS` to update.

```
 public static Action<int> myAction = x => doMethod(x);

 public static void doMethod(int rowIndex)
    {
        updateStatus(rowIndex, "testing");
    }

 public static void updateStatus(int row, string text)
    {
        listView.myList[row].status = text;
    }
```

I suspect that this isn't working because the `value` being passed into `X` is getting updated each `iteration` causing the only the last row in my `datagrid` to update?

Please could someone give me alternative options to have each `task method` update for the `row index` that matches the `task index`?

Thanks

PS: Please take it easy on me as I am self taught a very new to programming/ C#...

Comment: I don't understand how you call `myAction` as an instance of `p` whilst it's static.

Comment: Sorry I should mention the code is working fine. The only issue is that if I have multiple `tasks` and I run them all at the same time. Only **one** row/status is ever updated and actively changes. The other `tasks` do not update and I suspect this is because the `variable` 'X' is being updated each iteration. I thought that the `tasks` capture the 'X' `value` as they are but this doesn't seem the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `listView` class you have `private static string _status;`

So each List item access to this static field and `OnPropertyChanged` occured only once (see `if (_status != value)` check inside `status` property)

So try to add private field `private string _status;` to `listItems` class

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will give this a try when I get the opportunity later. 

So just to confirm you believe the `private static string _status;` should have `static` removed?

The problem I still think is that the `X` parameter is being updated per iteration causing it to only target the last iteration.

Comment: Yes, `_status` field should be moved inside `listItems` class without `static` modifier.

Comment: And about `X` parameter -  you can check it by adding `Debug.WriteLine(rowIndex)` inside `public static void doMethod(int rowIndex)`. But I suppose every task has different X parameter - because you declare this variable **inside** cycle

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate your help and guidance :) Will give it a go and update this further with the results

Comment: Just tested and amazingly it works a treat! Cannot believe I missed this and was looking at the wrong place all along wondering why this isn't working! Thank you very much for your help!